# How can I add close button in title bar of the activity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created custom title bar as suggested by this link:-= http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/

This is my window_title.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"

        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"

        android:background="#323331">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/header_label" 

        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Preview Song"
        android:textSize="10dip"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip">

     </TextView>  

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        android:src="@drawable/button_close"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"

        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my custom_title.xml:-

```
<resources>

    <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

But this is my result now-
![enter image description here][1]

It means title content (preview song and close image) are too small, I want to increase height of this title bar. I have increased the height of title bar but this is not increasing the size of title bar but the contents overlaps the title bar and these button and preview song does not display.

Please suggest me what mistake I am doing ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create custom title bar and hide android title bar in your activity you add just...

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"

and see this link::

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-create-custom-titlebar

Comment: thank you sir for your support, i designed custom title bar, but still some problem is there. please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

well samir second link working fine for me. Have a look at the following windows_title.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:background="#323331">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/header1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="5dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="5dip"
            android:textSize="11dip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/close"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/leadProgressBar1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleTvLeft"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can inflate a new custom layout of yours.